# How to use Python to check all neighbors in an array

Tags: python, python-2.7

So for a school project, I'm attempting to recreate a "Forest Fire Simulation" program in Python 2.7.
If you are not familiar with that, the rules are described [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Forest_fire)

I currently have my code set up to generate a 10x10 grid filled with 60% Ts, 30% Bs and 10% Ws, representing trees, blank spaces and fires respectively. What I'm having trouble with is figuring out how to make a function to go through and check all of the neighbors of a single place, needing to see if a tree is bordering a fire block in order to change the tree to a burning block on the next "tick". I've looked around a bit but cannot find anything that does this in the way I need it to.

Obviously I could just brute force it and have a different function for every square, but that wouldn't be practical at all, and it would only work as long as the grid stayed the same size. Any advice or help would be wonderful, and if you have any questions feel free to ask, sorry for being vague, as I'm a bit pressed for time asking at the moment. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: maybe you should look into "game of life" simulation as it uses the same principal ... allthough to be honest I have found starpng to be great for this sort of simulation

Comment: yeah very similar to Conway's Game of life. You could look into Numpy's `where` function to get locations of the trees, fires etc.

Comment: Look at [quad trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

Comment: What do you mean: *have a different function for every square*?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I didn't do all the work here, but you could set a dictionary with a key representing the numbers of the array (11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23 etc) and then cycle through the dictionary using the key to determine the surrounding neighbors and adjust the values accordingly.  You may need 2 dictionaries that mirror each other in order to get all your updates to flow correctly as you advance through the simulation.

Here is my basic premise:

```
import random
#a cell in the forest
class cell():
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = ''
#Creating the forest and populating randomly with value
forest = {}
i = 1
while i < 5:
    j = 1
    while j < 5:
        tcell = cell()
        rnum = random.randrange(1,3)
        if rnum == 1:
            tcell.state = 'T'
        elif rnum == 2:
            tcell.state = 'B'
        else:
            tcell.state = 'W'
        forest[str(i) + str(j)] = tcell
        j+=1
    i+=1
#iterating through forest and gathering values to adjust accordingly
for k,v in forest.iteritems():
    d1 = k[0]
    d2 = k[1]
    startstate = v.state
    NW = forest[str(int(d1)-1)+str(int(d2)+1)]
    N = forest[str(int(d1))+str(int(d2)+1)]
    NE = forest[str(int(d1)+1)+str(int(d2)+1)]
    W = forest[str(int(d1)-1)+str(int(d2))]
    E = forest[str(int(d1)+1)+str(int(d2))]
    SW = forest[str(int(d1)-1)+str(int(d2)-1)]
    S = forest[str(int(d1))+str(int(d2)-1)]
    SE = forest[str(int(d1)+1)+str(int(d2)-1)]
    if startstate == 'W':
        if NW.state == 'T':
            NW.state= "W"
        if N.state == 'T':
            N.state= "W"
        if NE.state == 'T':
            NE.state= "W"
        if W.state == 'T':
            W.state= "W"
        if E.state == 'T':
            E.state= "W"
        if SW.state == 'T':
            SW.state= "W"
        if S.state == 'T':
            S.state= "W"
        if SE.state == 'T':
            SE.state= "W"
```

Comment: The last for loop looks terrible.

Comment: @pal sch I'm sure you could clean it up, but the way I wrote it i feel demonstrates my thought process effectively.

The for loop is written that way so that the dictionary key can be used to find the neighbors.

NW | N | NE
 W  | C  | E
SW | S | SE

The answer is not a cleaned up polished solution but it is how i would start to go about it, and it works.

Comment: Yeah, when you want to understand the code, this solution is probably cleaner. You are right.